# Django Admin изменить виджет для ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-admin

При открытии в админке модели `CoinTransaction` поле `user` представляет из себя выпадающий список. Так как пользователей около 20тыс данная страница рендерится долго. К тому-же это не единственное поле `ForeignKey`. Нужно заменить виджет с выпадающего списка на поле ввода, в которое можно было бы вписать `User.id`

Сумел сменить виджет для ForeignKey, но данные не сохраняются. Выдает ошибку вроде этой:

> Cannot assign "30784": "CoinTransaction.user" must be a "User" instance

Примечание: `30784` - это ID пользователя `User`

**models.py:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Пользователь"""
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.last_name} {self.first_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

class CoinTransaction(models.Model):
    """Монеты пользователей"""
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Пользователь', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class CoinTransactionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Изменяем виджеты"""
    user = forms.IntegerField(label='Id пользователя')

    class Meta:
        model = CoinTransaction
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(CoinTransaction)
class CoinTransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Транзакции монет"""
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'amount', 'operation_type', 'order')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'user',)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Я не до конца понимаю смысл этого метода"""
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['form'] = CoinTransactionAdminForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Можете более детально объяснить задачу?, Добавьте пожалуйста все используемые модели?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko, дополнил описание вопроса. Модели не играют роли, смысл в изменении виджета для ForeignKey()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняем стандартный виджет на `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` с помощью создания своей формы

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import site
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget


class CoinTransactionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Изменяем виджет для ForeignKey"""

    class Meta:
        model = CoinTransaction
        widgets = {
            'user': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(CoinTransaction._meta.get_field('user').remote_field, site),
        }
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(CoinTransaction)
class CoinTransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Транзакции монет"""
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'amount', 'operation_type', 'order')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'user',)
    form = CoinTransactionAdminForm
```